# Script works fine without function. Turning it into one makes the program fail

Tags: python, function

```
def letter_guess():
    words="testing"
    letter_s = input("please enter a letter")
    if letter_s in "testing":
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

I dont know why defining the script as a function does not work. It will work without it however.

Comment: How exactly it's failing

Comment: Silly question, but... are you calling the function?

Comment: Function would not be executed if you don't call them. Also `class`.

Comment: I wasn't calling the function, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function, not just define it:

```
def letter_guess():
    words="testing"
    letter_s = input("please enter a letter")
    if letter_s in "testing":
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

letter_guess()
```